# How do I load data file to state array in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react.And I'm trying to load data file to a state array instead of directly placing array of data in the state.Below I've placed the code.But this doesn't display the data.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Projects from './Components/Projects';
import data from './data/data'

class App extends Component {

constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {

    myArrays: [{data}]

  }
}


render() {
 return (
    <div className="App">

    <Projects myArrays = {this.state.myArrays} />

  </div>
);
 }
 }

export default App;
```

It works if I replace

```
<Projects myArrays = {this.state.myArrays} /> with <Projects myArrays = {data} />
```

What is the difference between doing this two? And why doesn't it load data with

```
 <Projects myArrays = {this.state.myArrays} />
```

Project.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Projects extends Component {

render() {
let projectItems;

  projectItems = this.props.myArrays.map((project,i) =>{
    return(
    <li key = {i}>{project.title}</li>
  );
  });

  return (
  <ul>
  {projectItems}

  </ul>
  );
  }
 }

 export default Projects;
```

data.js

```
export default [
    {

    title: "Obama set for first political event since leaving office",
    category: "politics"
  },
  {

    title: 'La Liga refuse to accept PSG payment for Barcelona striker Neymar',
    category: "sports"
  },
  {

    title: "Virtu Financial closes KCG's European prop trading business",
    category: "business"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between

```
<Projects myArrays = {this.state.myArrays} />
```

and

```
<Projects myArrays = {data} />
```

is the way you are assigning data to the state

```
this.state = {

    myArrays: [{data}]

  }
```

This will result in `this.state.myArrays` which looks like

```
[{data: [
    {

    title: "Obama set for first political event since leaving office",
    category: "politics"
  },
  {

    title: 'La Liga refuse to accept PSG payment for Barcelona striker Neymar',
    category: "sports"
  },
  {

    title: "Virtu Financial closes KCG's European prop trading business",
    category: "business"
  }
]
}]
```

Replace it with

```
 this.state = {

    myArrays: data

  }
```

and your first version will also work

Comment: Consider Accepting the answer if it helped